# How to fetch records from database WordPress

Tags: database, wpdb

`index.php`:

```
 <?php $new=$wpdb->query("select * from wp_posts where post_title='Auto Draft'");
 $new1=mysql_fetch_row($new);
 echo $new1[0];
 ?>
```

How to fetch record from database?
How database works with WordPress files?

Answer (score 2):

`wpdb` is a simple wrapper around the `mysql_*` functions, but you can't mix and match them. `$wpdb->query` ***does not*** return the database reference that `mysql_fetch_row` needs. It ...

> ... returns an integer corresponding to the number of rows
>   affected/selected. If there is a MySQL error, the function will return
>   FALSE. (Note: since both 0 and FALSE can be returned, make sure you
>   use the correct comparison operator: equality == vs. identicality
>   ===).

[You have but to read the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

So, `$wpdb->query` is really for queries that don't return data, like a delete.

What you want is:

```
$new = $wpdb->get_results("select * from wp_posts where post_title='Auto Draft'");
```

You want `prepare` as well if you were using user supplied data.

```
$new = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("select * from wp_posts where post_title=%s",$str));
```

That will return an `object`, but you can pass a second parameter to get an `array`. You can iterate over that object or array with ordinary PHP object/array operations.

There is also `$wpdb->get_var` and `$wpdb->get_col`.

The database holds, as with any other PHP/MySQL applications, your dynamic content-- posts, pages, configurable options, category tables, etc. It is not an easily enumerable list.

As for the question in the comment, "which case we need to use most probably" No idea. Depends on what you are doing. That isn't really answerable, but I would say that in most cases you should not need, nor should you anyway, write SQL to manipulate the database. There are many core functions for that-- `WP_Query`, `WP_User_Query`, `set_option`, `update_post_meta`, `wp_update_post`, the continues for about twenty more lines.

Comment: oh so nice of you :) 
what is the role of database .i mean how to use queries of database in wordpress and  in which case we need to use most probably.thanks alot

Comment: @TusharSharma : See the edit.

Comment: @s_ha_dum can you please check the points below.  - You have mentioned `$wpdb->query is really for queries that don't return data, like a delete.`  but in case of a delete query `$wpdb->query` will return the number of records affected.  - You have used `$wpdb->results`. Should this not be `$wpdb->get_results`?

Comment: I meant "return data from the database"-- rows/values from the database. Yes, I believe all of the methods return some information about the query execution. Yes, it is `get_results`. I was probably writing in a hurry. :)